# How to change the XBox 360 setting to configure it for USA?

Tags: xbox-360

I have upgraded my XBox last week with the new updates. I am in USA, and for some reason it thinks that I am in India and showing me the Gold Membership purchase in Rupees.

I am looking for some apps, which I think it's not showing me because it thinks that I am in India. How can I change it?

Comment: Interesting! I am chatting with the support person, and they cant change the gamertag region because of laws dealing online services, digital content, copyright, and censorship laws in each country. Isn't it should be based on from where device is connected? now just because its associated with wrong country, its not even allowing to connect to netflix and few other apps. Those apps are only meant for USA because of their own copyright restrictions..

Comment: creating a new gamertag is free, and if you aren't subscribed to Live, and don't have a strong attachment to your gamerscore, it might be the best option.  MS doesn't tend to like to budge on these things, although if it's their fault you might get lucky.

Comment: good luck. MS has rubbed me the wrong way over the restrictions imposed by XBL more than once. It looks like sitting on the phone with them is the only way... so call em up!

Comment: @agent86 - its not my fault, as when it created the gamertag by default it didn't ask me to provide location details. For any interconnected system, I would expect that it at least prompt me to verify the location information when I am connecting xbox from US and creating the id with my non-USA live account which unfortunately i used after 3 years as otherwise its of no use for me.

Answer (score 6):

The country that the Xbox thinks you're in is [tied to your Gamertag](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/12/p/58203/316534.aspx), and not to any console settings.  You can change the console's language in the settings, but these two things are separate.

You can't normally change the country associated with a Gamertag, so it's a bit unusual that you're having this problem only recently.  You can either create a new Gamertag and pick the correct country, or if you've got some reason to keep your current tag, contact Xbox support and see if they can resolve whatever's gone wrong.

Comment: yes. I can see that my gamertag is associated with country india. how can i change it? any idea?

Comment: chatting with customer support. http://getsatisfaction.com/microsoft/topics/setting_gamertag_to_a_different_country_region

Answer (score 0):

You have to call Microsoft Xbox Live Support on the phone the request the change.
http://support.xbox.com/en-US/contact-us and request a call.